# Use Linq to get Top 10 Customers

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two POCO's

```
public class Customers
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming my Data Service returns a List<Customers> and List<Orders>, how would I use Linq to Get the Top 10 Most Active Customers (most orders)?

I want to return Customer.Id, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Count, (as Json from a controller action), so I created a new POCO to hold results. something like the following:

```
public class MostActive
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Although it's not working, here is what my current attempt looks like so far:

```
var results = (from c in Customers
              from o in Orders
              where c.Id == o.CustomerId
              orderby c.Id.Count descending
              select new MostActive
                  {
                      FirstName = c.FirstName,
                      LastName = c.LastName,
                      Id = c.Id,
                      Count = h.Id.Count
                  }).Take(10);
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I updated the question to show my current progress. I'm having trouble with the count, and thinking I need to do some grouping or something, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That code looks like a good starting point. What is `Id.Count` supposed to do according to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This involves a few steps, which you can break down as so:

1. Group orders by customer ID
2. Sort groupings by total
3. Get the top (first) 10
4. Associate the relevant customers
5. Create the result object

Something like this should do it:

```
var results = Orders
    .GroupBy(o => o.CustomerId)
    .OrderByDescending(og => og.Count())
    .Take(10)
    .Select(og => new {
        Customer = Customers.Single(c => c.Id.Equals(og.Key)),
        Orders = og
    })
    .Select(c => new MostActive {
        Id = c.Customer.Id,
        FirstName = c.Customer.FirstName,
        LastName = c.Customer.LastName,
        Count = c.Orders.Count()
    });
```

Or to carry on where you started from, which is nearly there, this will also work. As you said the main part is adding the grouping and then doing a join to customers:

```
var results = (
    from o in Orders
    group o by o.CustomerId into og // create a grouping of orders by customerID
    orderby og.Count() descending // sort by number of orders in each grouping
    join c in Customers on og.Key equals c.Id // og.Key is the grouping Key (CustomerId)
    select new MostActive
    {
        FirstName = c.FirstName,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        Id = c.Id,
        Count = og.Count()
    }).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

With foreign keys properly defined this should be easy

```
    Customers.Select(c => new MostActive {
              FirstName = c.FirstName,
              LastName = c.LastName,
              Id = c.Id,
              Count = c.Orders.Count()
              })
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
        .Take(10);
```

Foreign keys are defined in database. Under linq I assumed Linq2SQL or EF, both generate those relations automatically from database.

Comment: I am not sure how to define the foreign keys. I just have two separate lists as described. This is not connected to a database directly, just lists that have hand coded example data. Please elaborate on how to define foreign keys. Is it something I do in the POCOs, or are you talking about a database definition?

Comment: This is certainly true, and a good answer, for [tag:entity-framework] where entities have navigation properties, but not relevant here as EF is not mentioned.